# Spark Scala Split DataFrame by some value range

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

Suppose I have a dataframe with a column named `x` with a value range of `[0, 1]`. I hope to split it by the value of column `x` with ranges like `[0, 0.1)`, `[0.1, 0.2)`...`[0.9, 1]`. Is there a good and fast way to do that? I'm using Spark 2 in Scala.

Update: Ideally there should be 10 new dataframes that contain data for each range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on @Psidom's solution for creating ranges, here's one approach to create a dataframe for each range:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType
val df = Seq(0.2, 0.71, 0.95, 0.33, 0.28, 0.8, 0.73).toDF("x")
val df2 = df.withColumn("g", ($"x" * 10.0).cast(IntegerType))

df2.show
+----+---+
|   x|  g|
+----+---+
| 0.2|  2|
|0.71|  7|
|0.95|  9|
|0.33|  3|
|0.28|  2|
| 0.8|  8|
|0.73|  7|
+----+---+

val dfMap = df2.select($"g").distinct.
  collect.
  flatMap(_.toSeq).
  map( g => g -> df2.where($"g" === g) ).
  toMap

dfMap.getOrElse(3, null).show
+----+---+
|   x|  g|
+----+---+
|0.33|  3|
+----+---+

dfMap.getOrElse(7, null).show
+----+---+
|   x|  g|
+----+---+
|0.71|  7|
|0.73|  7|
+----+---+
```

[UPDATE]

If your ranges are irregular, you can define a function which maps a Double into the corresponding Int range id, then wrap it with a `UDF`, like in the following:

```
val g: Double => Int = x => x match {
  case x if (x >= 0.0 && x < 0.12345) => 1
  case x if (x >= 0.12345 && x < 0.4834) => 2
  case x if (x >= 0.4834 && x < 1.0) => 3
  case _ => 99  // catch-all
}

val groupUDF = udf(g)

val df = Seq(0.1, 0.2, 0.71, 0.95, 0.03, 0.09, 0.44, 5.0).toDF("x")
val df2 = df.withColumn("g", groupUDF($"x"))

df2.show
+----+---+
|   x|  g|
+----+---+
| 0.1|  1|
| 0.2|  2|
|0.71|  3|
|0.95|  3|
|0.03|  1|
|0.09|  1|
|0.44|  2|
| 5.0| 99|
+----+---+
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more on dfMap? And do you think this way is efficient? Thanks!

Comment: The transformations for creating `dfMap`, which is a `Map` with distinct `g` as the keys and dataframes (with corresponding `g`) as values, involve collecting distinct `g` into a local array, converting into a list, and creating a `Map` of filtered dataframes for every element in the list.  These transformations apply to the entire data set hence aren't cheap.  I'd say they're worth doing if you plan to perform extensive computations on selected dataframes in `dfMap`.

Comment: I see what you point. The thing I'm trying to do is calculating the sum of x for each category(`g` here). Is there any good way to do that?

Comment: In that case, there is no need to spin off those dataframes for every `g`.  You can simply do this: `df2.groupBy($"g").agg(sum($"x"))`

Comment: Not sure I follow the logic in your last comment.  You might want to start a separate question with more thorough description and sample cases.

Comment: I see! However, if the range is not evenly divided, e.g., [0, 0.12345), [0.12345, 0.4834)..., is there a good way to split it(or groupBy it)? Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.cysl, please see my expanded answer.

Comment: udf is a brilliant idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to discretize a double typed column, you might just do this (multiply the column by 10 and then cast it to integer type, the column will be cut into 10 discrete bins):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType

val df = Seq(0.32, 0.5, 0.99, 0.72, 0.11, 0.03).toDF("A")
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [A: double]

df.withColumn("new", ($"A" * 10).cast(IntegerType)).show
+----+---+
|   A|new|
+----+---+
|0.32|  3|
| 0.5|  5|
|0.99|  9|
|0.72|  7|
|0.11|  1|
|0.03|  0|
+----+---+
```

Comment: I want 10 new dataframe and do some further computation. I'm thinking to use `.filter()` but I'm not sure this works and this is fast enough(the data is huge).

Comment: Instead of creating 10 new dataframe, you might need `groupBy("new")` and then do whatever you need for each group.

Comment: I will try that!